# Running a python script produces: ImportError: no module named termcolor

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a new virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv --python=python3.2
```

Then, I activate the virtual environment and install packages:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install termcolor
$ python -m termcolor
```

This all works just fine.  I then install my own project called Hermes which uses termcolor:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

But when I run the executable that's installed to the virtualenv's bin directory, I get an error:

```
ImportError: no module named termcolor
```

How do I install termcolor?

Comment: `But when I run the executable that's installed to the virtualenv's bin directory` .. what is this executable doing? Can you paste the bootstrap script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another python executable must be in the path. Are you doing sudo or does your python file have a `#!/usr/bin/env python` line or anything? Try `python -v` and `which python` to figure out which python you are actually using. Are you running venv/bin/python?

Comment: the python in my path is the one in the venv/bin directory.  The script has #!/Users/scott/projects/hermes/venv/bin/python as the first line... not sure what else to look for.

Answer (score 10):

The error:

```
ImportError: no module named termcolor
```

Means you have not installed termcolor.  Here is how you install it for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install termcolor
```

The exact command to install it for your linux distribution will depend on the package manager.  When you're done with that, put this in a python script to make sure it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from termcolor import colored
print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
```

The script should print hello in red, and world in green.  Then you know it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be for you to make sure that your virtual env is active when you're running your app!
Sorry if it sounds like dumb advice, but make sure that you're inside the virtual env, so the executable that gets called has all the modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you in windows, you can use this for example:

windows 7, 32 bit [runing your cmd]

```
 - set path=%path%;c:Python27
 - cd downloads
 - cd termcolor-1.1.0
 - python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below command before trying to import it

```
!pip install termcolor
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).